# How to use Position and select text by using vscode extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was trying to write an extension for vscode.
The function is that to select the texts in Brackets. But stuck in the begining.
When i want to use Position as follows, it throws exception
var pos = new Position(1, 1);

Can anybody share some sample code to me?

Comment: I am using javascript instead of typescript

Comment: Depends on your imports. If you just have `var vscode = require("vscode");` then you have to write `var pos = new vscode.Position(1, 1);`.

Answer (score -2):

Just coping Mike's answer (which was inserted as a comment):

Depends on your imports. If you just have `var vscode = require("vscode");` then you have to write `var pos = new vscode.Position(1, 1);`